# How to know (programmatically) when a query is done on PostgreSQL/Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to programmatically check for a query's status in Redshift/PostgreSQL ?
How do I know when a query has completed running ?

I have an application to run a series of SQL queries sequentially. It runs a query and waits for it to finish before executing the next query. I need to know when a query is done running.

I can't run them synchronously because sometimes, Redshift/PostgreSQL does not provide relinquish control after the query is done executing (for long queries). is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at **[stv_recents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_RECENTS.html)** table in Redshift.

For example to retrieve a list of currently running queries run:

```sql
select pid, trim(user_name), starttime, query
from stv_recents
where status = 'Running'
order by starttime ASC;
```

Comment: I use the table stv_recents to manually check if my query is done executing. but I don't see how I can use that from code, there might be multiple people running the queries (with same user_name),

Comment: You can check if `query` column matches your query. You can also add some random comment to SQL and check if it's in Running state.

Comment: Thanks. with every query I run, I add a UUID as a comment in order to check query status.

Comment: Is there a similar table as stv_recents where I can inspect whether a query has thrown an exception while executing ?

Comment: Only [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) like queries can throw an error during execution. It's errors are stored in [STL_LOAD_ERRORS table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html).

Any other queries won't be executed if there is any problem with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Redshift always relinquishes control when the query finishes. If your application is not receiving that control it means you've experienced a TCP timeout / keepalive issue.

Here are the docs for fixing this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html